Error 'html5lib not found' when using pandas.read_html() function in google cloud composer 2.1.8
I have a code to scrape data from a website. I used pandas.read_html() and wrote everything in a dataproc. When I run the code in (Composer &)Airflow somethimes it runs successfully and sometimes it fails with this error:
Job failed with message [ImportError: html5lib not found, please
install it]. Additional details can be found at <log>

My code:
bq_client = bigquery.Client()
df = pd.DataFrame()

for page in range(1,100):
    url = "my url"
    html = requests.get(url).content
    df_list = pd.read_html(html)
    df = pd.concat([df, df_list[-1]], ignore_index = True)

Update: Can I include a piece of code in my code to install the package while it is running on dataproc?

As the error says, you'll need to install the html5lib package. You can install it in the same way you've configured for some version of pandas to get installed.

I installed it on my computer. It fails in composer

Yes, but somehow you've told Composer that you need pandas - use the same method, whatever it has been, to also specify you need html5lib.
